# CLion: How do I get coverage for the actual library code instead of just the tests

Tags: cmake, clang, code-coverage, clion

I am testing a C++ library and I want to record coverage when I run the tests. Based on the [CLion documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/code-coverage-clion.html), I added the necessary compiler switches:

```py
option(CODE_COVERAGE "enable code coverage" OFF)

if(CODE_COVERAGE)
    if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "(Apple)?[Cc]lang")
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping")
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Code coverage only available with LLVM/clang.")
    endif()
endif()

add_library(libfoo SHARED
    # ... snip: source files ...
    )

# ... snip: library deps & config

add_executable(libfoo_tests
    # ... snip: source files ...
    )
target_link_libraries(libfoo_tests gtest_main libfoo) # using Googletest
```

With this, I can run the tests with coverage in CLion. And I get coverage reports… on the testing code, but not on the library's code. So this is pretty much useless.

I have no idea what CLion actually does when running the tests with coverage, but the [docs on LLVM's coverage tool](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-cov.html) state clearly that

> BIN may be an executable, object file, dynamic library, or archive (thin or otherwise).

So it should be possible to get coverage on the library. What do I need to do to make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. If you remove that code, you would get an error (described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/code-coverage-clion.html), that automatically creates a new debug profile with the flags needed for the code coverage. This time the src folder is included (even not perfect), but maybe from there you could find a perfect solution.

Comment: Well my workaround was to make the library `STATIC` when `CODE_COVERAGE` is on, which does yield proper results and is good enough for me. I won't put more effort into it but if someone can derive the proper solution from this, I will accept it.